# Output of command when piped to another command

Tags: shell-script, find, pipe, xargs

I am running a command which does a quick checksum of some file like so

```
find / -type f -ctime +30 -mtime +30 -atime +30 -exec md5sum {} \; | xargs -P 4
```

and I am trying to run it in parallel with

```
xargs -P 4
```

Now, when I run the find command, by itself, I see output as each file is being checksummed. But when I pipe it to xargs, I no longer see the output of the find command.

Is there a way I could see the output of find when it is piped to another command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want this:

```
find / -type f -ctime +30 -mtime +30 -atime +30 -print0 | xargs -0 -P 4 md5sum
```

You want the list of files to be fedinto the md5sum command.  This is done with `find / | xargs md5sum`.  Then you want to not have to worry about crazy characters (spaces, newlines, whatever) in filenames, so we use `-print0` for find and `-0` for xargs.

Answer (score 4):

I took your command,

```
$ find / -type f -ctime +30 -mtime +30 -atime +30 -exec md5sum {} \; | xargs -P 4
```

And figured we want to redirect, while still echoing to stdout.  One way we can do this is with tee

```
$ man tee | head
NAME
   tee - read from standard input and write to standard output and files
```

So, tee will definitely write to stdout (which is what we need to continue the chain), and also write to a file of our choosing.  Great!  But what file?

Thanks to this answer for the idea https://stackoverflow.com/a/9405342, we can use

```
/dev/tty
```

for our redirect, and it will print to our console!

So, for the full command:

```
$ find / -type f -ctime +30 -mtime +30 -atime +30 -exec md5sum {} \; | tee /dev/tty | xargs -P 4
```

I start seeing some great text roll down the screen as I do that :)

Comment: I like your answer because I wouldn't have thought of using tee to output it to /dev/tty.  Thank you very much